# What does it mean @Inject in Angular component?

Tags: angular, angular8

There is this in constructor of component:

```
export class MyDialogComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

 constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any
  ) {}

}
```

What does it mean: `@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 4: When and why is @Inject is used in constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47050450/angular-4-when-and-why-is-inject-is-used-in-constructor)

Comment: Why not simple:  constructor(public data: any)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**0) Definition of @Inject**

The Angular [Inject](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/di/angular2/inject_and_injectable) decorator definition taken from rangle.io:

> @Inject()
>
> @Inject() is a manual mechanism for letting Angular know that a
>   parameter must be injected.

**1) Definition of MAT_DIALOG_DATA**

From the angular [material dialog api](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api):

> MAT_DIALOG_DATA
>
> Injection token that can be used to access the data that was passed in
>   to a dialog.

**2) Usage of @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) from the material documentation**

In the [dialog docs](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) you can find how to share your data with a dialog component.

If you want to share data with your dialog, you can use the data option to pass information to the dialog component.

```
let dialogRef = dialog.open(YourDialog, {
  data: { name: 'austin' },
});
```

To access the data in your dialog component, you have to use the MAT_DIALOG_DATA injection token:

```
import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'your-dialog',
  template: 'passed in {{ data.name }}',
})
export class YourDialog {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }
}
```

**3) Full stackblitz example**

Additional the material documentation provides a simple [full working example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/lpykbmblada?file=app%2Fdialog-data-example.ts) at stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

Within such a factory function, using this function to request injection of a dependency is faster and more type-safe than providing an additional array of dependencies (as has been common with useFactory providers).

Dependency Injection (DI) recapitulation 
If you use Inject then you don't need to pass service in providers: []